# Java version for Android Bumble Bee

Tags: java, version

I have an Android studio with Bumblebee. Should i download a JAVA SE development kit and install it or is it not required? There is an in-build JDK11 which i could see in the project settings so was in a confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

1. first install a [JDK 11](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) on your computer, to support all your tools also. Most of Java Tools are developed in Java.
2. then you will need to download the Android SDK from your Android Studio IDE. Go to **Tools** > **SDK Manager**

[image]

Comment: I could see already an Embedded java here.I could check it from project structure/sdk location and jdk location.So, do i still need to download Java development kit .

Comment: @Ducktales yes you still need to download a jdk, not only for your IDE but all the other programs that will need to use Java. And also you can configure your IDE to point to another jdk